# Sharing data between arduino and android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

do you know any good tutorial, which can explain me how can I do stuff like that? I found few, but non of them provided clear android code. I've tried, to look in android docs, but I cannot find anything useful at all. **I'm not looking for code, but for tutorial, which explain how to.**

Thanks, Galunid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using bluetooth, looking at your tags. If so,

- what version of bluetooth? 2, 4, ...?
- What "protocol"? I mean, usually you do this through a serial port emulation.

What is the BT module you are using?

If it is a bluetooth 2 serial emulation, Arduino will see it as a common serial port, so any serial port tutorial is ok. As for Android, I'd look for "Android serial bluetooth" on google... There are plenty of tutorials there...

If you are using BT4, I never used it and I only know that things are a bit more complicated on the android side. But if you look on google searching "Android ###" where ### is your bluetooth module you are using probably you will find some infos.

Comment: Helped a lot. Thanks